# Store uploaded images tdefinitely based on their json representation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minimagick

Hello everyone since the past hour i've been trying to use minimagick gem, but i can't figure out why i can't open an image. the return value is always null

i have the following code in my controller:

```
class UploadController < ApplicationController
    require 'mini_magick'

    def load
        file = "public/uploads/cache/img.jpg"
        image = MiniMagick::Image.open(file)
        render json: image
    end
end
```

On a get to upload#load
i get a null value.

i have installed minimagick on my mac using homebrew.
i restarted the server.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the variable `@image` coming from? - thats your error right there

Comment: that's a mistype! sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering `local variable` `"image"` instead `instance variable` `"@image"`

```
def load 
  file = "public/uploads/cache/img.jpg" 
  @image = MiniMagick::Image.open(file) 
  render json: @image 
end
```